# Android MotionLayout Swipe to reveal

Tags: android, animation, android-motionlayout

I have a list of items  that can be swiped away using a `MotionLayout`. I wanted to implement an animation similar to the one in the Gmail android app, where when you swipe an email away, there is that colored background that gets revealed. So what I tried is to place an `ImageView` in the `MotionLayout`under the view that moves, so that when that view goes away it will reveal the `ImageView` beneath.

Here is the layout of the element:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
        android:id="@+id/reading_list_item_motion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/reading_list_item_scene">

        <!-- The image under the element that moves -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reading_list_item_back"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/reading_list_item_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/search_result_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/search_result_padding"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/reading_list_item_icon"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/ic_search_result"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/ic_search_result"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="Search result icon"
                app:error="@{@drawable/ic_default_search_result}"
                app:imageUrl="@{book.best_book.small_image_url}"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/reading_list_item_info_layout"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_default_search_result" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/reading_list_item_info_layout"
                android:layout_width="316dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/reading_list_item_icon"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/reading_list_item_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="@{book.best_book.title}"
                    android:textColor="@color/textSecondary"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/reading_list_item_author"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text='@{"by " + book.best_book.author.name }'
                    android:textColor="@color/textSecondary" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

Even though in the Design editor the image appears to be there, and if I play the `MotionLayout` transition everything behaves as expected, when starting the app the `ImageView` is nowhere to be seen.

Another approach that I thought of would be to append the `ImageView` at the end of the view that moves, so that when it starts to go off-screen, the `ImageView` comes in view. I am not sure how could I implement this though since the `ImageView` should be as wide as the screen and `match_parent` obviously wouldn't work

Does anyone have any idea how can I implement this animation?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is an image of how I'd like it to look. The more the item goes of screen, the more of the red background gets revealed.
[image]

Here is the MotionScene xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/reading_list_item_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        <Constraint
            app:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/reading_list_item_layout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"
        app:constraintSetStart="@+id/start">
        <OnSwipe
            app:dragDirection="dragRight"
            app:touchAnchorId="@id/reading_list_item_layout"
            app:touchAnchorSide="left" />
    </Transition>
</MotionScene>
```

Comment: can you post any image regarding this animation?

Comment: @NehaK I've added the picture

Comment: can you post layoutDescription layout : reading_list_item_scene

Comment: @NehaK I've just added it

Comment: Your code works fine for me, I added red color to the "reading_list_item_back" & white to "reading_list_item_layout"

Comment: You ran it in the emulator or on device?

Comment: on the device...

Comment: Just tested it on device, and it's not working for me. Can you post your code to github to compare it with mine? Maybe the problem with my code is not directly related to the layout

Comment: ok let me post it

Comment: check this out https://github.com/NehaKushwah993/SwipeRevealAnimationUsingMotionLayout

Comment: did this work for you?

Comment: Just run your project. Yes, it works on my machine as well. And at first glance the rest of the code looks pretty similar to mine. At least now I know the layout is right

Comment: Ok, so I found the problem...kinda. For some reason the source of the `ImageView` isn't getting rendered(even though with a transparent background on the `ConstraintLayout` i could see the image in the designer). But setting a background as you did worked. The image that I would actually want to display was an icon anyways so adding a `Button` as you did should work just fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: .....welcome :)

Comment: You don't really need a MotionLayout for that. What about a swipe callback instead?